# Materialize Center Buttons Horozontally on grid

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I'm working on https://rapptor.co . I have used Materialize as the framework and I'm making a login modal, I'm trying to center the buttons at the bottom of the modal with center-align, however It's not working.

```
    <!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Login Details</h4>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">person</i>
                <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="first_name">Username/Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">security</i>
                <input id="first_name" type="password" class="validate">
                <label for="first_name">Password</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: -30px;">
            <div class="col m4 s12">
                <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat red lighten3">Close</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col m4 s12">
                <a href="#!" class="modal-action waves-effect waves-orange btn-flat orange lighten-3">Help</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col m4 s12">
                <a href="#!" class="modal-action waves-effect waves-green btn-flat green lighten-3">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest anything for me to try?

Thanks!

Comment: where is ur css

Answer (score 0):

remove `float:right;` and insert try following css at line no:13

```
.row .col.m4 {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your modal footer like this way, just run this snippet you can see the difference, hope this will help you

```css
.modal-footer {
 text-align:center;
}
.modal-footer a {
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0 15px;
 float:none; /*if you set float already */
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat red lighten3">Close</a>
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action waves-effect waves-orange btn-flat orange lighten-3">Help</a>
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action waves-effect waves-green btn-flat green lighten-3">Login</a> 
</div>
```

if you set this you button show like this picture

[image]

i dont know this is what you need , thats why i put an image here